# Application of Euler Cromer algorithm to coupled differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

I have a situation where a tennis ball is hit at an angle Θ<sub>0</sub> from some height y<sub>0</sub> above the ground.
The equations representing this motion are :

dv<sub>x</sub> / dt = -k v (C<sub>D</sub> v<sub>x</sub> - C<sub>L</sub> v<sub>y</sub>) ;

dv<sub>y</sub> / dt = - g - k v (C<sub>L</sub> v<sub>x</sub> + C<sub>D</sub>v<sub>y</sub>).

Here v<sub>x</sub> = v cos Θ and v<sub>y</sub> $= v sin  Θ$ , C<sub>D</sub> is drag coefficient and C<sub>L</sub> is lift coefficient.

To solve these equations  using Euler-Cromer algorithm I need two functions $g(t,x)$ and $f(t, v)$ , such that

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = g(t, x) ; \frac{dx}{dt} = f(t, v)$$.

I really do not know how to reduce these two equations to the required functions (being a coder i am not very good at mathematics). The link to related article is : [Calculations of ground stroke trajectories](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340804129_Calculations_of_groundstroke_trajectories_in_tennis)

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use a symplectic algorithm in a situation without energy conservation? Any other higher order method will give better results.

Comment: I'm actually required to do it that way !

Comment: So you have $v'=F(v)$ and $x'=v$. At the base Euler-Comer just means to use the new value of one variable on the right side of the other, so it is still quite explicit to compute $v_{+1}=v+hF(v)$ and then $x_{+1}=x+hv_{+1}$. In the current case this has no deeper sense than to produce comparable results with a slightly non-standard method (or an implementation that is so on purpose, often hasty implementations of explicit Euler end up this way).